# Cómo evitar que una imagen docker cambie el propietario de ficheros en Linux

Tags: docker

Estoy haciendo un curso de PHP en Linux. Para las pruebas creo una imagen así:

```
docker run -d  -p 8080:80 -v $PWD:/var/www/html richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
```

La cuestión es que cambia el propietario y grupo de todos los ficheros y directorios con estos nombres:

```
systemd-timesync  systemd-journal
```

¿Alguien sabe cómo se evita esto?

Comment: Es un problema de coincidencias de `id` de usuario, no es nada grave. El `id` en tu máquina tiene un nombre diferente al que tiene la misma `id` dentro de la imagen docker.

Comment: Al final baje una imagen php:7.4.4-apache y no le pasa eso. Pero me gustaría saber cómo solucionarlo para usar nginx en vez e apache.

Comment: Te lo explico en una respuesta.

Comment: ¿Fue mi respuesta de utilidad? ¿Sigues teniendo alguna duda? No dudes en dejarme un comentario si he dejado algo en el tintero.

Answer (score 2):

Para corregir el problema de permisos debes crear tu propio `Dockerfile` a partir del usado en [`richarvey/nginx-php-fpm`](https://github.com/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm/blob/master/Dockerfile). Para ello descárgate una copia del repositorio para hacer las modificaciones:

```
git clone https://github.com/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm.git
```

Observa las [líneas 70 y 71](https://github.com/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm/blob/5f7fcc2d5fbd3edefd76eac3e5270122be7000c2/Dockerfile#L70) del archivo `Dockerfile`:

```
  && addgroup -S nginx \
  && adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/nginx -s /sbin/nologin -G nginx nginx \
```

En Debian/Ubuntu el usuario que sirve páginas web, `www-data`, tiene el `id` número `33`:

```
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) grupos=33(www-data)
```

Esta imagen docker cambia el usuario y grupo del trabajador php-fpm de `www-data` a `nginx` en las [líneas 265 y 266](https://github.com/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm/blob/5f7fcc2d5fbd3edefd76eac3e5270122be7000c2/Dockerfile#L265):

```
    -e "s/;listen.owner = www-data/listen.owner = nginx/g" \
    -e "s/;listen.group = www-data/listen.group = nginx/g" \
```

Una solución podría ser hacer coincidir el `id` del usuario `nginx` con la `id` del usuario `www-data` para que, aparentemente, no haya ninguna diferencia entre ellos. Para hacerlo debes cambiar las líneas 70 y 71 anteriores por éstas:

```
  && addgroup -S --gid 33 nginx \
  && adduser -D -S --uid 33 -h /var/cache/nginx -s /sbin/nologin -G nginx nginx \
```

Ahora ya puedes generar la imagen docker con:

```
docker build .
```

Y aunque se traten de usuarios diferentes (`nginx` en la imagen docker y `www-data` en la máquina anfitriona), como coincide su `id`, seguirás viendo en tu máquina anfitriona los archivos con el dueño `www-data.www-data`.

Si quieres que el dueño sea otro, adapta el procedimiento al deseado.

---

Yo, personalmente, no te recomiendo tener un servidor web en cada contenedor docker desplegado. Es una sobrecarga de memoria innecesaria. En su lugar usa tantas imágenes de trabajadores **php-fpm** como necesites basados en [`php:fpm`](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&name=fpm) y un único **nginx** en tu máquina anfitriona como frontal hacia ellos.